# Updating Policy Template in Windows Server 2016 to Include Relaxed Minimum Password Length Limits Feature

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server-2016, windows-server-2022

I'm working on a Windows Server 2016 AD server and noticed that the option to relax minimum password length limits is not available in the group policy editor. I understand that this feature is available in Windows Server 2022. Is there a way to update the policy template in Windows Server 2016 to include this new setting or a workaround to achieve the same result?

Comment: “Is there a way to update the policy template in Windows Server 2016 to include this new setting or a workaround to achieve the same result?” - Try installing [KB4601318](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/february-9-2021-kb4601318-os-build-14393-4225-expired-c5e3de6c-e3e6-ffb5-6197-48b9ce16446e). [Explanation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/minimum-password-length-auditing-and-enforcement-on-certain-versions-of-windows-5ef7fecf-3325-f56b-cc10-4fd565aacc59). Update of course is expired. I can’t help you get the update

Comment: @Ramhound Would that be the only way to get updated policy template? If i would to install KB5022289, would it include all the previous updates?

Comment: Yes; KB5022289 is a cumulative update which superseeds all cumulative updates before

Comment: @Ramhound I have tried to install KB5022289. But it says that the update is already installed on this computer. But when i check my group policy, it still does not have the updated security poliy

Comment: Then you have answered your question. You will have to upgrade to Windows Server 2022 to use that policy